dj-rest-auth/login doesn't work with 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [ 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',], in postman
I am not an expert of setting up the settings file in DRF. I want to use React and DRF for authentication and this is my code
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',

    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'social_django',    
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
    ]
MIDDLEWARE = [
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    
     'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
     'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware',  #allauth

]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
]
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

#allauth
SITE_ID= 1 
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
         'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
      
    )
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
   "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)

#simple jwt
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT','Bearer',),
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=600),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": False,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": False,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": True,
    "ALGORITHM": "HS512",
}
# rest auth
REST_AUTH = {
    'USE_JWT': True,
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'access',
    'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE': 'refresh',
    'JWT_AUTH_HTTPONLY': False,
    'SESSION_LOGIN': False,
    'OLD_PASSWORD_FIELD_ENABLED': True,
}


**when i am trying to make a request with this config in postman at  /dj-rest-auth/user/  i get this
message {
    "detail": "Given token not valid for any token type",
    "code": "token_not_valid",
    "messages": [
        {
            "token_class": "AccessToken",
            "token_type": "access",
            "message": "Token is invalid or expired"
        }
    ]
}

although in browser works (because is self managed by django whatsoever) . if i want to gain an access and refresh token i must change the config to :**
  'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', 
    )

but then it doesn't work for /dj-rest-auth/user/ request (in postman) and i get
 {
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}. 


i switch it back to
'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication'

/dj-rest-auth/user/ request (in postman) works just fine
{
    "pk": 1,
    "email": "demo@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Denis",
    "last_name": "Andrew"
}

any recomandation please ? i tried this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtm325DL1io&list=PLKzFrEuFEga5LQN7cAVvo1VwdSD783sUn&index=3
but idk why it doesn't work for me. maybe i don't see the difference

First part of Authorization HTTP Header is the token type.
Authorization: <type> <value>

I noticed you've set
#simple jwt
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT','Bearer',),
    ...
}

in your djangorestframework-simplejwt settings.
AUTH_HEADER_TYPES setting controls what tokens types are allowed in the Authorization Header. Documentation
With that being said, make sure you've added the Bearer prefix before the access_token in your Authorization HTTP Header.
I should look like this:

Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
OR
Authorization: JWT <access_token>

I've created a simple tutorial on how to set up the JWT authentication in DRF:
Django REST APIs with JWT Authentication using dj-rest-auth
